# UITableView cell layout differences with iPhone 12 pro and promax

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am seeing a different layout behavior for cells in a table view between iPhone12 Pro/ProMax and other iPhone versions. This behavior is seen in the Xcode simulator and on physical phones.

(iPhone 11 on left below)

[image: Screenshot of table view]

Is this "correct" behavior? It's the same app code in both cases. The app's not doing any of the layout in code, layout is configured in the attributes inspector in the storyboard.

The green background is the cell's content view containing the image view. The image view's content mode is Aspect Fill.

Comment: Glad I read all of your question before posting my comment. One thought - what if you had **no** image view but just a UITableCell with a red background color? Same result?

Comment: To test with no image view, I set cell.cellImage.image = nil in cellForRowAt. Result in this case is I do see margin space in each row.

Answer (score 1):

Just set it for imagewView in cell

```
yourImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Yes that does restore the margin between images and above the first image. Although there is more clipping of the image. Oddly there is no clipping at all in the iPhone11 case, regardless of the clipsToBounds setting.